# What is the difference edge_weight and edge_attr in Pytorch Geometric

Tags: graph, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I want to handle weighted undirected graphs in Pytorch Geometric.
The node features are 50 dimensional. I found that this can be handled by the `x` attribute of the `torch_geometric.data.data` class.
The weights of the edges are scalar values.
We found out that `edge_attr` and `edge_weight` are the attributes to handle edges.

I think I should probably use `edge_weight`, is this correct?

Also, what is the difference between `edge_attr` and `edge_weight`?

I'm not very good at English, so I apologize for that.
I hope I can get a good answer.

Thank you.

Comment: This answer might be useful https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/16805/is-there-an-open-source-implementation-for-graph-convolution-networks-for-weight

Answer (score 9):

The difference between `edge_weight` and `edge_attr` is that `edge_weight` is always one-dimensional (one value per edge) and that `edge_attribute` can be multi-dimensional. You can check the [cheatsheet](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/cheatsheet.html) for the support of the models.

Comment: No, the edge attribute contains features for the edges which can be used to calculate the message in a learnable way. The edge weights just scale the messages.

Comment: @PascalIv doesn't that implies also that edge weights have to be one-dimensional? I tested a forward pass of a GATConv layer and it works also if you pass an edge_weight tensor which has multiple dimensional so it is still not clear and the documentation does not help in any way

Answer (score 3):

The difference between `edge_weight` and `edge_attr` is that `edge_weight` is the non-binary representation of the edge connecting two nodes, without `edge_weight` the edge connecting two nodes either exists or it doesn't(0 or 1) but with the weight the edge connecting the nodes can have arbitrary value.

Whereas `edge_attr` means the features of the edge connecting any two nodes. These feature can be multidimensional.